# Upgrading gettext in Ubuntu 16.04 to version of 17.04

Tags: 16.04, gettext

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

I'd like to install `gettext` version `0.19.8.1-1ubuntu2` on my computer?

- Can I easily install it on Ubuntu 16.04?
- Should I install it after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Manually)

The easiest solution is to install it manually.

1. Download a copy of `deb` package for your Ubuntu architecture from here:

   - amd64: https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/amd64/gettext/download
   - i386: https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/i386/gettext/download
2. I have already checked the dependencies of this package on my own Xenial using `gdebi --apt-line gettext_0.19.8.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`, everything was satisfiable.
3. You can install it like:

   ```
   sudo apt install gettext_0.19.8.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
   ```

   it will install any necessary dependencies for you, if you are missing them.

**Note** that you'll not going to get any update for this package, you have to update it yourself.

#### Using repositories)

In this way you'll get the updates, first you have to add `zesty` repositories to your `/etc/sources.list.d/`, then add something like:

```
APT::Default-Release "xenial";
```

to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` it will  make `Xeinal` your default sources, after that you have to pin this package by adding something similar to:

```
Package: gettext
Pin: release n=zesty
Pin-Priority: 900
```

into `/etc/apt/preferences`.

Read in more details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto.

Comment: I am getting error : E: Unable to locate package gettext_0.19.8.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb when running sudo apt install gettext_0.19.8.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
. This package is there in my downloads folder

Comment: you have to `cd` into Downloads first: `cd ~/Downloads`, then try installing it.

Comment: I `cd` into Downloads, then `ls` ,it showed deb package in it with red coloured letters. Then i ran the command and it showed error.

Comment: I used `sudo dpkg -i gettext_0.19.8.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`. Worked for me. :)

Comment: @NidhiGupta that would the work too, however if you miss any  dependency `dpkg` can't handle that, that was why I suggested using `apt` ;)

Comment: Thanks. By the way can you tell me why wasn't it working for me?

Comment: I guess you have to address it like: `sudo apt install ./pkg.deb`

Answer (score 0):

In the default repositories gettext 0.19.8.1-1ubuntu2 is in Ubuntu 17.04 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/gettext). In 16.04 there is gettext 0.19.7-2ubuntu3.
So, you would get gettext 0.19.8.1-1ubuntu2 automatically if you install or upgrade to 17.04. But you could also manually install the package of 17.04 for 16.04 with dpkg.